# why vscode linter dont show errors when jsx code is inside js file

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I'm starting to learn React (18). There is something that has surprised me a lot.
When creating an application with Create React App, I have come across a `.js` file that has a method that returns html and yet VSCode does not give me an error. It detects everything perfectly despite having no plugin installed, no config file and the file is not jsx.

I have read the documentation (https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#whats-a-jsx-transform ) and I understand that jsx is an extension of js, and that when the application is compiled, it goes through Babel and the code is translated.

But when you open the project with VSCode, without compiling, it naturally understands the jsx code despite being inside a js file.

How is that possible? What is the mechanism that makes VSCode understand that code?

example:

```js
// App.js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: _"no plugin installed, no config file"_ - what do you think Create React App/`react-scripts` is doing?

Comment: and react/scripts doesnt explain how vscode detect correctly jsx code inside a js file

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found that this is because VSCode natively supports JSX code regardless of whether it is in .js or .jsx files. It has nothing to do with project dependencies or configurations.

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_jsx-and-auto-closing-tags